# table of the number of occurrences of numbers in the column postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count

I have a table:

[image: picture]

My select:

```
select  regexp_split_to_table(t3."Id"::character varying,'') as s
from (select t1."Id" from table1 t1
union all
select t2."Id"from table2 t2) t3
order by s
```

Or also I can get a string '22173345566179111134546175622323811' with this:

```
select  string_agg(t3."Id"::character varying,'') as s
from (select t1."Id" from table1 t1
union all
select t2."Id"from table2 t2) t3
```

I need to get a table with **number|count** data, I mean for any number to get a count of repetitions in the select, for example:

1 | 9

2 | 5

3 | 5

and so on..

PostgreSQL DBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way

```
select regexp_split_to_table(t3."Id"::character varying,'') s,  count(*) count
from (select t1."Id" from table1 t1 union all select t2."Id"from table2 t2) t3
group by s
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select id, count(*)
from (select t1."Id" from table1 t1
      union all
      select t2."Id" from table2 t2
     ) t3
group by id
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want a list of all digits, that exist in a set of IDs from two tables and the count of each digit, how often it appears in all these IDs. If so, you just need to `GROUP BY` a digit and use `count()`.

```
SELECT s.d,
       count(*) count
       FROM (SELECT t1."Id"
                    FROM table1 t1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT t2."Id"
                    FROM table2 t2) t3
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL regexp_split_to_table(t3."Id"::character varying, '') s(d)
       GROUP BY s.d
       ORDER BY s.d;
```

Comment: absolutely correct, but... I don't understand, why do you use s(d) - what is that? function? and I see "group by" and "order by" - s.d.  Doted. It's a little bit complicated...

Comment: @NikMatue: It's no function, it a alias defining `s` as alias for the "result table" of `regexp_split_to_table()` and `d` as an alias for the first column of that result.

Comment: Is there any documentatioan about this aliases?